Biasing a Capacitive Amplifier
I am studying capacitive amplifiers.
Please refer to the following circuits of capacitive amplifiers. Both of them operate at a power supply of VDD. The two circuits only differ by the biasing scheme where one uses RB at opamp inputs to bias them to half VDD, while the other uses feedback resistors to bias the inputs at half VDD.
I have a question regarding feedback. Is it necessary to create a dc path between the output and input terminals of an opamp as the bottom circuit does? Does the top circuit need some sort of dc feedback path to correct the error in case there is an output offset between VOP and VON (e.g. VOP = 0.8V, VON = 1V)?



Consider Switched-Cap Common-Mode Feedback circuits. You can check Razavi's Analog CMOS Design book.

a360pilot Thank you very much for the reply. I’ll check it out

The fundamental problem is that every DC voltage within your amplifier, i.e. every gate voltage, drain voltage, etc. needs to be well-defined. This is what we call biasing.
You might think, naively, that defining the input voltage is enough to let all the other node voltages be defined in your input. Well, nothing further from the truth.
For every Ids and Vds in your circuit (I'm assuming a CMOS process here), there needs to be a gate-source voltage and gate current (even if it's nA or pA). You can only do this via negative feedback assuming the entire amplifier is DC-coupled (i.e. no coupling capacitors between amplifier stages).
Feedback needs a sense and a control mechanism to work properly. In your top amplifier, the 1st stage output has a Vds that will be sensed by the 2nd stage input. The Vds of this 2nd stage will be sensed by the 3rd stage, but, then, this output is not used to control anything. We have sense mechanisms, but no control mechanism. On the other hand, if you were to connect to the resistor from output to input, then the 1st stage input (a gate voltage I presume) works as the control mechanism to regulate the amplifier.
You may say, but why? If I fix the input voltage of the 1st stage, wouldn't everything else be defined? Well, if you don't put any signal and you, somehow, are able to tightly control the environment of this amplifier (temperature, interference, etc)... maybe. But now, think about what happens when you put a signal on top of it, every single small-signal parameter of this amplifier will move with the signal, there's no counteraction to keep the gate voltages at every stage at the same DC level, any small-signal estimation you've done is invalid, because there is no small signal within the amplifier anymore.
There might be feedback for AC signals, but the DC will be all over the place within this amplifier.
A while back, I answered another question about a capacitive feedback amplifier that did not include any feedback resistor. Instead, they handled the biasing of each stage locally. The way they did it was quite complicated, but their purpose was something else other than linear amplification. If you read it, you'll see that they use negative feedback within the amplifier to keep each stage biased, without having to resort to overall DC negative feedback (like a resistor would do).

Thank you very much for your explanation.  May I please restate the reason in my own words to let you see if I have understood the concept correctly?  The idea is to make sure every node voltage in the amplifier is well defined. For the top circuit, although the input gate voltage is biased at half the supply rail through Rb, the circuit still lacks a control voltage (information from its output) to help regulate itself. From DC’s point of view, the opamp behaves like an open-loop configuration rather than the buffer configuration shown in the bottom circuit.

@Kenlucius that's correct. Check in my other answer how that other capacitive feedback amplifier is biased, it doesn't matter how, every node needs to be forced to a DC position. Every node needs to be well-defined.

Thank you very much for your help.


Is it necessary to create a dc path between the output and input terminals of an opamp as the bottom circuit does?

I believe you are on the right track. To stabilize the DC operating point of these amplifier circuits, you need DC negative feedback. The second circuit already has this (it is a voltage follower configuration), but the first one does not. So you should introduce it similarly (by connecting resistors between the output and input). It will not be as effective as the one in the second circuit because there will be some DC gain, but it will still work.

Thank you very much for the explanation. Is it correct that I summarize the issue as follows? From the DC’s point of view, the opamp in the top circuit behaves like an open-loop configuration, while that in the bottom circuit has a buffer configuration. The top opamp is only regulated at AC not DC.

@Kenlucius, I completely agree with you.

Thank you very much for your help.
